# How do I display non printable chars in rich edit?

Tags: delphi, winapi, character, richedit, non-printable

is there a way how to display any of the [non-printable characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_control_characters) in TRichEdit control ? Or at least [paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow) at the end of each line ?

I've made a quick preview to the [rich edit messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff486015%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) but can't see anything specific for this purpose. I'm just curious about it hoping there's a cleaner way than replacing chars (at least for that paragraph).

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that the Windows Rich Edit control supports this. You might consider using a different text editor control.

Comment: I think Scintilla can do this since Notepad++ does so.

Comment: In addition, you are probably talking about 'hidden characters' (e.g. #$20, #$09, #$0C, and #$0A), and not general 'control characters', such as 'start of header', 'end of transmission', 'end of text', 'bell', 'shift in', etc.

Comment: @Andreas - yes, about the _hidden characters_ whose displaying would make sense and which can be displayed in usual word editors.

Comment: Are you displaying rich text? Or are you displaying plain text?

Comment: @David - yeah, the rich text. Initially, for the paragraph, I was hoping there is some setting in the [PARAFORMAT2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787942%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) structure but it seems Andreas was right and it's really unsupported by [RichEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787605%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) control.

Comment: So it's a Word like thing rather than a Notepad like thing.

Comment: @David - I was just wondering if it's supported by RichEdit. At least those paragraphs.

Comment: I guess you can do it yourself, by simply adding a paragraph sign after each paragraph. I doubt there is a setting that makes TRichEdit do this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature in TRichEdit.

If you had [TRichView](http://www.trichview.com/) you could just set `rvoShowSpecialCharacters` in the `RichViewEdit.Options`, and then call `RichViewEdit.Reformat`.

Comment: +1 and accept; TRichView looks nice, but the price.. The most important for me is that it's not supported by TRichEdit. Thanks

Comment: I know that some delphi tools like Help&Manual that started out using RichEdit dropped it for dozens of reasons.  They now use TRichView, and the experience (I am a user of Help & Manual) is worth the price. Using RichEdit is not so great in any commercial application, for anything other than fairly trivial purposes.  I wouldn't write a word processor, help file editor, or even an insurance company form-letter-editing tool with RichEdit.